# Atualização de Dados Power BI

Tags: powerbi

Tenho um servidor SQL Server e um gráfico pronto.
Estou utilizando DirectQuery.

Quando entro no dashboard do power bi e mando 'atualizar agora', no histórico, consta como atualizado com sucesso. Porém, ao acessar meu gráfico (publicado na web) os mesmos não estão atualizados..

Comment: Caso voce crie um relatório novo como esses dados eles permanecem antigos , ou estão atualizados? E qual a versão do PowerBi? Na versão gratuita existem algumas limitações para atualização das informações

Comment: Quando crio um novo, os dados ficam atualizados! É a versão gratuita, de estudante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel oque está acontecendo é o seguinte.

Os dados/dashboards do powerBI podem ser trabalhados em dois formatos diferentes.

O primeiro é o **DESKTOP**

Nele você trabalha com o aplicativo instalado no seu PC

O segundo é o **ONLINE**

Voce manipula os dados aqui através da web, sem ser necessária nenhuma instalação prévia em seu PC.

No seu caso você criou seu gráfico no DESKTOP, e vinculou alguns dados do seu SQL. Após ter realizado isso você publicou o arquivo, e nesse momento tanto seu gráfico quanto seus dados (que ficam dentro do próprio arquivo do powerBI) foram para a nuvem, e ficaram disponíveis para acesso ONLINE.

Acontece que quando você clica em 'ATUALIZAR' no app Desktop ele atualiza o arquivo na sua máquina e não na web. Ou seja, para atualizar tanto o gráfico quanto os dados que você deseja será necessário novamente 'PUBLICAR' o arquivo ( substituindo assim o anterior).

Para não ter de publicar novamente toda vez que atualizar alguma coisa voce pode utilizar um item chamado 'Gateway de dados'

Segue um link explicando essa questão:

[Gateway de Dados](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/pt-br/gateway/)